# How do I pass arguments to bound methods? bind vs. anonymous methods

Tags: javascript

I tried replacing the method name with a method w/ arguments below but this did not work.

```
// just a minimizer method

function m5(a,b)
  {
  return document.getElementById(a).onkeypress=b;
  }

// On page initialization thse methods are bound to text input boxes

m5('signin_pass',bind_enter_key(event,interface_signin));  // this does not work
m5('upload_file',bind_file_upload);
```

Comment: Putting parentheses after the function name calls the function immediately. Sounds like you want [function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: You are still calling the function. See the "examples" section in the page I linked to.

Comment: @ChrisAaker: Specifically, look at the "currying" example. It shows how to create a function with a preset argument

Comment: Could you show the code for bind_enter_key and bind_file_upload and also explain what you are actually trying to do? I don't think you need function binding/proxying at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this with an anonymous function that calls your function with the correct parameters:

```
// just a minimizer method

function m5(a,b) {
  return document.getElementById(a).onkeypress=b;
}

// On page initialization these methods are bound to text input boxes

m5('signin_pass', function(event) {bind_enter_key(event,interface_signin)});  // this does not work
m5('upload_file', bind_file_upload);
```

This creates an anonymous function which is passed to m5 as the function and that anonymous function calls your function with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: @missingno - assuming `event` it's meant to be the keypress event, I added that to the anonymous function declaration.

Comment: Went with this b.c. I can understand the instructions for the bind method

Answer (score 0):

What does your `bind_enter_key` function return?
It should return a function as you assign it to `onkeypress` event. If you want to call `bind_enter_key` function with predefined parameters on keypress event, then you need to build a closure:

```
m5('signin_pass',function(event){
  bind_enter_key(event,interface_signin);
});
```

Just a note, I believe `bind_enter_key` and `interface_signin` are global and accessible in this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
m5('signin_pass',bind_enter_key(event,interface_signin));  // this does not work
//first argument is a string, works when passed to getElement..
//second argument is the result of a function call bind_enter_key.
//if the function returns something other than a function, the assignment to a handler will fail

m5('upload_file',bind_file_upload);
//second art is a function, as it should be
```