# How do I use bind() properly?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pass arguments to bound methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058862/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-bound-methods)

How do I use bind() in this instance.
I need to bind a function ...but the code below calls it.  How do I use bind().  I read the MDN documentation but it did not make sense.

bind_enter_key and bind_file_upload are methods i wrote.

[mdn documentation on bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
m5('signin_pass',bind_enter_key(event,interface_signin)); // this does not work
m5('upload_file',bind_file_upload);

// just a minimzer

function m5(a,b)
  {
  return document.getElementById(a).onkeypress=b;
  }
```

Comment: EXACT same code (with the same code comments even) is posted in two separate questions by two different user names.  Either this is homework or one person is double posting via two user names.  The dup [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058862/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-bound-methods/8058993#8058993) has already been answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, you really made this confusing by using `bind` in two different ways (one in your function name and one in the operation you want to perform on that function).

```
m5('signin_pass', bind_enter_key.bind(null, event, interface_signin));
```

Note that you seem to be binding to the current value of `window.event` by doing this, which is probably a horrible idea. Better might be

```
m5('signin_pass', function (event) {
    return bind_enter_key(event, interface_signin);
});
```